# jQuery function not working properly

Tags: jquery

Hello again SO community.

Is there something wrong with this piece of code:

```
(function ($) {
jQuery.fn.submitAsync = function (adHocOpts, addFormObserver, skipValidation) {        
    $.each(this, function (i, form)
    {
        if (!$(form).data('submitOptions') && addFormObserver)
            $(form).trigger('formLoad');

        $(form).data('adHocOptions', $(form).data('submitOptions'));

        $(form).mergeOptions('adHocOptions', adHocOpts);

        var options = $.extend($(form).data('adHocOptions'),
        {
            type: form.method,//.attr('method'),
            url: form.action,//.attr('action'),
            data: $(form).serialize()
        });

        if (skipValidation)
            options.validation = [];            
        setTimeout($.ajax(options), 10);

    });
};})(jQuery);
```

I keep getting an Unexpected identifier error, and the execution is halted. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: When the console points an error, it gives the precise location.

Comment: can you look at the console and say which line is throwing the error

Comment: It doesn't, surprisingly!!! Which is why i am so frustrated, because i cannot pinpoint the location of the error!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Previous answer was incorrect, try this instead:

```
setTimeout(function() {$.ajax(options)}, 10);
```

I used this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vasRL/2/ to get to the error, and found that it was being triggered on the setTimeout function.

Comment: I just rechecked and looks like you are right, the code is perfectly valid. I think i managed to recreate your error in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vasRL/, now to try to fix it

Comment: Thanks a bunch, you're a life saviour.